# Using Ubuntu, how come the screen saver is a black screen when running on the battery?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, battery, netbook, screensaver

I have an F-spot screen saver made and selected to run after a time period of inactivity. When the AC is connected, the screen saver runs after the select time, but when running on battery the blank screen (black screen) is selected instead. How can I change this? The computer is not in a suspended state in the battery mode either. Is this a default I cannot change?

I am using 10.04 LTS on a netbook Samsung n150.

Comment: It's probably to save power.

Comment: I don't know, but I was reminded of [this](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#gnome-screensaver)

Comment: @Nifle, but can I not change this? Although there may be a reason behind this I would still like to have the images.

Comment: If I knew *how* to change it I would have written an answer. You can probably find what you are looking for in the [Power Management Configuration](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ubuntu_10.x_Screensaver,_Desktop_Lock_and_Power_Management_Configuration) somewhere. And when you do be please answer your own question here on SU.

Comment: Do not do it. A screen saver and an active display will be consuming battery at a much higher rate than if you just let it as it is. The fact that the computer is not suspended does not mean that the CPU is not chilling out. If you run a screensaver, you will put a load on the CPU. Load on the CPU = battery consumption. And the display also consumes plenty of battery power for just being on.

Comment: @MikeNakis, how significant is the screensaver's consumption also taking into account the CPU part as well as the screen?

Comment: I cannot give numbers. But it adds up.  Using a screen saver certainly does not consume as much energy as playing a game, (100% CPU, 100% graphics) but also certainly not as little as when typing a document in a word processor. And when you are on battery you want it to last as long as possible, no?